# Which permission required in order to get ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG inside broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using the manifest file for creating broadcast receiver, for `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`.
But I can't get the broadcast when headset is connect/disconnect,
Which `permission` should I use inside the manifest file in order to be able to receive `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` broadcast intent?

Answer (score 4):

With API 8, I got my broadcast receiver called without creating a service or requesting for extra permissions.

You can define an inner class within your main activity similar to the one I've defined below:

```
public class HeadSetBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i("Broadcast Receiver", action);
            if( (action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))  == 0)   //if the action match a headset one
            {
                int headSetState = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0);      //get the headset state property
                int hasMicrophone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0);//get the headset microphone property
                if( (headSetState == 0) && (hasMicrophone == 0))        //headset was unplugged & has no microphone
                {
                               //do whatever
                }
            }           

        }

    }
```

Then, register your broadcast receiver either dynamically or statically. I registered mine dynamically in my Activity's onCreate() method:

```
this.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

Make sure that you unregister your BroadcastReceiver with the Context's unregisterReceiver. In my case, I did this in the onDestroy() method. That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a permission thing, it's actually a problem with how you registered the receiver. The headset plug action broadcast can only be received by actively registered receivers like this:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

This means that you need to have a service kept alive that holds a reference to the receiver and also unregisters it when the service is killed. Lastly, the service that registers the receiver needs to also be started on boot; which you do with yet another receiver that intercepts the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent. For this part, you will need to use the `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

For a full example of a service that does this stuff, you can check out an [app I wrote that does just that](https://github.com/jakebasile/hearing-saver/blob/master/src/com/jakebasile/android/hearingsaver/RegistrationService.java#L46).

Comment: How do you know which actions from android.intent.action.* can be used without having an active service running? Like in this case if I did  <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY"/> I would not need a service to detect head phone removal. I looked at the android documentation and cannot tell which services can broadcasts can simply be used by registering in the manifest.